# Get dataset from JSON by parameter

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, search

Trying to find unique dataset from JSON using my parameter.

I've got JSON "userDetails":

```
{
"userDetails": [
                {
                "name": "Sabine",
                "imageUrl" :"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/82.jpg",
                "content": [
                            {
                            "type": "video",
                            "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Travaho.mp4"
                            },
                            {
                            "type": "image",
                            "url": "https://picsum.photos/640/1136/?image=281"
                            }
                            ]
                },
                {"name": "Keila Maney",
                "imageUrl" :"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/81.jpg",
                "content": [
                            {
                            "type": "image",
                            "url": "https://picsum.photos/640/1136/?image=273"
                            },
                            {
                            "type": "video",
                            "url": "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4"
                            }
                            ]
                }
                ]
```

}

I know that my user is **Keila Maney** (I've got that users attribute in my code) and need to send that parameter to JSON, and receive back ONLY **Keila Maney** attributes (it's imageUrl, content (type, url)) and then parse them.

Are there any standard methods for searching in JSON?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does this mean `need to send that parameter to JSON`?

Comment: There is no standard. It depends on the backend

Comment: It means that in JSON I've got a lot of records, and I need to filter out them with my parameter (in my case parameter is "name"="Keila Maney")

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Example of Json:

```
{  
  "places": [  
    {  
      "name": "Ulrikh",
      "id": 555,
    },  
    {  
      "name": "Place 2",  
      "id": 1,  
    }
]  
}
```

Call:

```
 self.getDataByID(id: 555)
```

Swift Methods:

```
func getDataByID(id : Int) {
        let data = self.getData()
        
        
            for i in 0..<data.count
            {
            if(Int((((data as NSDictionary)["places"] as! NSArray)[i] as! NSDictionary)["id"] as! Int) == id)
            {
                print("here is result:")
                print((((data as NSDictionary)["places"] as! NSArray)[i]))
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getData() -> NSDictionary {
        do{
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "json")
            let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)
            let jsonResult:NSDictionary!  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData! as Data , options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            return jsonResult
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
        
        return NSDictionary()
    }
```

don't thank :)

Answer (score 1):

Just create object of UserDetails like: `var userData: [UserDetails]?`
and check this in a loop `userData[x].name == "Keila Maney"`. then this x will be your index for Keila Maney and your can fetch its all data. After binding your json data to UserModel object. These are the three classes you will create from your json

1. UserModel

   ```
   struct UserModel : Codable {
   let userDetails : [UserDetails]?

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case userDetails = "userDetails"
   }

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      userDetails = try values.decodeIfPresent([UserDetails].self, forKey:.userDetails)
   }

   }
   ```
2. UserDetails

   ```
   struct UserDetails : Codable {
   let name : String?
   let imageUrl : String?
   let content : [Content]?

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

       case name = "name"
       case imageUrl = "imageUrl"
       case content = "content"
   }

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
       name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
       imageUrl = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .imageUrl)
       content = try values.decodeIfPresent([Content].self, forKey: .content)
   }

   }
   ```
3. Content

   ```
   struct Content : Codable {
   let type : String?
   let url : String?

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

       case type = "type"
       case url = "url"
   }

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
       type = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .type)
       url = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .url)
   }

   }
   ```